# AutoCompleteTextView dropDown height is incorrect

Tags: android, listview, autocompletetextview, android-popupwindow

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` with custom item_layout. If `layout_width` is not `match_parent` there is a scrollbar showing even I have only one hint when hint is too big. But if we use width `match_parent` there is no scrollbar. I want to use limited width for `AutoCompleteTextView` anchor without that annoying scroll.
This is the code.

**item_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.xml** with limited width(200dp for example)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/anchor"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_complete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@id/anchor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Result with limited width of anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gGez.png)

**main.xml** width=match_parent

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/anchor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_complete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@id/anchor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Result with width="match_parent" anchor parameter no scrollBar!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49cqk.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autocomplete_dogs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/Autocomplete"
android:hint="Search dogs..."
android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/header"
android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
/>
```

And here is the complete guide [AutocompleteTextView](https://materialdoc.com/components/autocomplete/)

Comment: I don't want to use DropDown width bigger than anchor's.